# how to set tab order only in particular column of datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set tab order only on a particular column. such as i have 2 columns (ID and Name).  so tab reflects only on "Name" column . When i press tab it goes to next line in the same column vertically.

Comment: I dont understand please edit, show some code or Explain more

Comment: What kind of control are you using? @King King maybe on the right track but I would use the controls KeyDown Event and if you are using a GridView then you should be able to set its ID columns TabStop to false.

Comment: @N4TKD you are right, at least `Tab` can be handled in `KeyDown`, maybe the only key we can't handle in `KeyDown` is `Enter`, that's when you have to use `ProcessDataGridViewKey` instead.

Comment: e.KeyChar == '\r' in a if statement works for Enter key in KeyDown or KeyPress on some controls I think.

Comment: @N4TKD it works if the cell is not in edit mode. The case here is if the cell is in edit mode. In edit mode, you have to register `KeyPress` event handler with the `EditingControl`, however even `Enter` can't be caught in such handler.

Comment: @King King i was sure KeyPressEventArgs would give you KeyChar, I will have to test it.

Comment: @N4TKD you don't have to test, I'm talking about `Cell in edit mode` (I hope you understand what edit mode is and how to know if a cell is in edit mode).I've discussed this problem and tried many times to help a guy sorting his problem out, his problem was the `Enter` key couldn't be caught in any key event (KeyPress, KeyUp, KeyDown) when the cell was in edit mode, while other keys were caught OK.

Comment: @King King I foolow you, but in KeyPress you can check for the char '\r' so you know Enter was the pressed key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to override the `ProcessDataGridViewKey` method to catch the `Tab` key and select the cell yourself, like this:

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{    
    //This contains all the column indices in which the tab will be switched vertically. For your case, the initial index is 1 (the second column): VerticalTabColumnIndices.Add(1);
    public List<int> VerticalTabColumnIndices = new List<int>();    
    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab&&VerticalTabColumnIndices.Contains(CurrentCell.ColumnIndex))
        {
            int i = (CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1) % Rows.Count;
            CurrentCell = Rows[i].Cells[CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
            return true;//Suppress the default behaviour which switches to the next cell. 
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }
}
//or simply you can handle the Tab key in a KeyDown event handler
private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab){
     e.Handled = true;
     //remaining code...
     //.....
  }
}
//in case you are not familiar with event subscribing
yourDataGridView.KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
```

Comment: from above answer i m facing same problem .

Comment: @user2607573 the code works well because I tested it, if not for you, you should consider everything if possible. The code works with forward tab, not backward tab (SHIT + TAB).

Answer (score 0):

Columns in dataridview have no tab order
1) You can either override the keydown event for handling tab.
2) Another easy way is by pressing Up, Down, Left, Right keys to navidate through the datagrid view.